# How can I apply a texture randomly on a object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I started Blender recently, and I'm working on my first "big" project alone.

I'm creating a "backrooms", and I want to make my floor a little bit dirty and old looking with stains.
I tried to play with voronoi and noise texture, but I can't find a way to get the result that I want.

My goal is to randomly apply a texture on an object that already has a material.

There is what I currently have on my floor:

[image: screenshot of my nodes]

Comment: Are you trying to apply a random texture or are you saying that an object has a random chance of having a specific texture? The way you've described it is a bit confusing. You went from voronoi  on the floor to random applications to different objects.

Comment: Oops sorry if I'm not being clear enough. In addition to my carpet material on the floor, I want a mold/moisture texture at random places on the floor.
I hope I better described it ahah

Comment: You were on the right track with voronoi or noise texture. Just use a color ramp node to to adjust the prevalence. Noise will probably be more what you want. Then use that value into a mix shader node's factor. I'll make an answer with a picture in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the mix shader node. You can put your two shaders into the input and then use the noise or whatever as the factor for mixing between the two.

[image]

You can also use weight painting or vertex colors to manually draw where you want the mold.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your quick answer!